# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript

Why is my JavaScript failing?

I'm an amateur within this field and suspect the solution is very simple...

```
function drawAnalysis() {
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("il");


    var pie = new RGraph.Pie({
            id: 'i1',
                data: [4,3],
                options: {
            colors: ['blue', 'rgb(255,255,255)'],
            labels: {
                            self: ["",""],
            },
            radius: 213,
            exploded: [0]
                }
    }).roundRobin()

});
```

}

I'm not sure that I'm allowed to show the RGraph.Pie script here due to copyright issues but the line failing reads like this

```
        this.context           = this.canvas.getContext ? this.canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: (typeof id === 'object' && id.alpha === false) ? false : true}) : null;
```

I appreciate any help :-)

Comment: You've typed the ID two ways, first with a lowercase L, then with the number 1

Comment: Well spotted - now I receive another error. Se comment below

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript debugger will make it immediately obvious what's going on. I use Firebug in Firefox; there are several good alternatives.

The error message means that you are somehow attempting to evaluate null.getContext. In the line of code you posted, this can only occur if this.canvas === null. This is probably occurring due to the apparent typo pointed out by adeneo. Alternatively, you may have failed to assign a valid value to this.canvas before executing this line; or perhaps the value of 'this' is something other than what you expect.

Additionally, assuming you are using jQuery, you could make the following improvements:

$( document ).ready(function()

can become simply:

$(function() { /* do stuff */ });

document.getElementById("il")

can become

$('#il')

Comment: Correcting the typo helped - but now I get a new error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of null" The related line is: this.context.translate(0.5,0.5);

Comment: So the value of this.context is probably null. Install the debugger, and use it to verify that.